# Apply results of pandas groupby to multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
    PO  SO        Date  Name  Qty
0  123  34  2020-01-05  Carl    5
1  111  55  2020-10-10  Beth    7
2  123  12  2020-02-03  Greg   11
3  101  55  2019-12-03  Carl    3
4  123  34  2020-11-30  Beth   24
5  111  55  2019-04-02  Greg    6
6  202  99  2020-05-06  Beth   19
```

What I would like to do is replace dates with the minimum date for the dataframe when grouped by `PO` and `SO`. For instance, there are two rows with a `PO` of '123' and an `SO` of '34'. Since the minimum `Date` among these rows is '2020-01-05', both rows should have their `Date` column set to '2020-01-05'.

Thus the result would looks like this:

```
    PO  SO        Date  Name  Qty
0  123  34  2020-01-05  Carl    5
1  111  55  2019-04-02  Beth    7
2  123  12  2020-02-03  Greg   11
3  101  55  2019-12-03  Carl    3
4  123  34  2020-01-05  Beth   24
5  111  55  2019-04-02  Greg    6
6  202  99  2020-05-06  Beth   19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform` with `groupby` to create a "calculated column", so that you can avoid a messy `merge`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'PO':  [123, 111, 123, 101, 123, 111, 202], 
                  'SO':   [34, 55, 12, 55, 34, 55, 99], 
                  'Date': ['2020-01-05', '2020-10-10', '2020-02-03', '2019-12-03', '2020-11-30', '2019-04-02', '2020-05-06'], 
                  'Name': ['Carl', 'Beth', 'Greg', 'Carl', 'Beth', 'Greg', 'Beth'], 
                  'Qty':  [5, 7, 11, 3, 24, 6, 19]})

df_grouped = df.copy()
df_grouped['Date'] = df_grouped.groupby(['PO', 'SO'])['Date'].transform('min')
df_grouped
Out[1]: 
    PO  SO        Date  Name  Qty
0  123  34  2020-01-05  Carl    5
1  111  55  2019-04-02  Beth    7
2  123  12  2020-02-03  Greg   11
3  101  55  2019-12-03  Carl    3
4  123  34  2020-01-05  Beth   24
5  111  55  2019-04-02  Greg    6
6  202  99  2020-05-06  Beth   19
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this, we will create a key using `PO`, `SO`, and the minimum `Date` for each combination of `PO` and `SO`. We use `groupby` with `min` to accomplish this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'PO':  [123, 111, 123, 101, 123, 111, 202], 
                  'SO':   [34, 55, 12, 55, 34, 55, 99], 
                  'Date': ['2020-01-05', '2020-10-10', '2020-02-03', '2019-12-03', '2020-11-30', '2019-04-02', '2020-05-06'], 
                  'Name': ['Carl', 'Beth', 'Greg', 'Carl', 'Beth', 'Greg', 'Beth'], 
                  'Qty':  [5, 7, 11, 3, 24, 6, 19]})

df_grouped = df[['PO', 'SO', 'Date']].groupby(by=['PO', 'SO'], as_index=False, dropna=False).min()

print(df_grouped)

    PO  SO        Date
0  101  55  2019-12-03
1  111  55  2019-04-02
2  123  12  2020-02-03
3  123  34  2020-01-05
4  202  99  2020-05-06
```

Now we can merge this with the original dataframe, replacing the old `Date` column with the `Date` column from `df_grouped`.

```
df = pd.merge(df.drop(columns=['Date']), df_grouped, on=['PO', 'SO']) 

df = df[['PO', 'SO', 'Date', 'Name', 'Qty']] # reset column order

print(df)

    PO  SO        Date  Name  Qty
0  123  34  2020-01-05  Carl    5
1  123  34  2020-01-05  Beth   24
2  111  55  2019-04-02  Beth    7
3  111  55  2019-04-02  Greg    6
4  123  12  2020-02-03  Greg   11
5  101  55  2019-12-03  Carl    3
6  202  99  2020-05-06  Beth   19
```

Comment: I am interested in simpler solutions for those who can come up with one. Is there a way to accomplish this without creating a separate "primary key" dataframe?